# UWP and External Lib Dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have a solution with several UWP projects that are using "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection"

I can't see any references in NuGet Package Manager to this extension nor in the project s References.
Using VS, how can I list all these external dependencies that my solution is using for each project inside.

Comment: The package does not support UWP.  The package installer races a bit too fast to see the error message, but you can see it from the Package Manager Console window when you type "Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection -Version 2.1.1"

Comment: If I create a new UWP project, I can see the package installed, and I get no errors installing it. The problem is this solution that I have that is using some version of the "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" but I can t see it in the Package Manager nor in References, but the application runs fine and is using it for sure. So my problem is that I don't have any information in the solution that shows that reference to the "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection". I can see in the dll that the version is 2.0.17205.

Comment: The UWP project is targeting Windows 10 Fall Creators update 10.0 build 16299, as min and target versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP and External Lib Dependencies

I can install the nuget package `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` to the UWP project, which target Windows 10 Fall Creators update 10.0 build 16299 without any error.

I can also see it in the Package Manager and in References:

[image]

[image]

So, please double check if it in the Package Manager under the Installed tab nor in References.

If you still can not see it, please try to restart your Visual Studio and PC, and try to uninstall and reinstall the nuget package.

> how can I list all these external dependencies that my solution is
>   using for each project inside.

You can right on your **solution** in the Solution Explorer, then select **Manage NuGet Packages for Solution ...**, you will get following window:

[image]

You can find the external dependencies that your solution is using for each project inside.

**Update:**

> My problem is that I don't know how many more references are mangled,
>   and I can t search for something that I don't know it exists

When you don't know how many more references are mangled, you can just delete the globe cache of nuget package, the default path is `C:\Users\<UserName>\.nuget\packages`. When you build the project, VS will re-download those packages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, as I told before in new projects I can see the reference, the problem is in this solution that does not list dependencies correctly. I also know that reinstalling the missing reference will make it appear in the references and NuGet Package manager... My problem is that I don't know how many more references are mangled, and I can t search for something that I don't know it exists... This is a very large solution with many projects

Comment: When you don't know how many more references are mangled, you can just delete the globe cache of nuget package, the default path is `C:\Users\<UserName>\.nuget\packages`. When you build the project, VS will re-download those packages.

Comment: @J_PT, I have updated the comment to the answer. Since that helps you resolve the issue, you could accept it as an answer. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread and we could close this thread, thanks.